# Java - ConcurrentModificationException

Tags: java, concurrentmodification

The following piece of code throws a ConcurrentModificationException almost every time it is called. The second piece of code does not throw the exception, however it is not the correct logic that I need. If the object is an instance of `EditorFrame`, I need to invoke a custom disposal strategy which is what the `close()` method is. However if it is just a basic frame I want it to call `dispose()`.

I've looked around this site and followed some instructions, but none that I found have worked.

The code that throws the exception:

```
synchronized (frameList) {
    for (Iterator<JFrame> it = frameList.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
        JFrame frame = it.next();
        if (frame instanceof EditorFrame) ((EditorFrame) frame).close();
        else frame.dispose();
        it.remove();
    }
}
```

This code works, but it's not what I want:

```
synchronized (frameList) {
    for (Iterator<JFrame> it = frameList.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
        JFrame frame = it.next();
        frame.dispose();
        it.remove();
    }
}
```

Thanks for helping!

Comment: Does you `EditorFrame.close` method modify `frameList`? (The current thread will hold the lock on `frameList`. Locks are re-entrant. Shouldn't need a lock, as Swing should be used only from the Event Dispatch Thread (EDT).)

Comment: Could you post the EditorFrame class?

Comment: Agree with Tom Hawtin: you should only be doing this code on one single thread, the EDT, and so should not need synchronization. Which line throws the exception by the way? Also, all if/else blocks, for loops, shoot any code block should be enclosed in curly braces to avoid ambiguity.

Comment: does frame.close() remove frame from frameList, or modify it in any way? that would explain the ConcurrentModificationException even from a single thread.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Without getting in to exactly what is causing the ConcurrentModificationException. you are still removing every object from `frameList`

why don't you clear the list explicitly after you finished iterating the list.

```
synchronized (frameList) {
    for (JFrame frame : frameList) {
        if (frame instanceof EditorFrame) ((EditorFrame) frame).close();
        else frame.dispose();
    }
    frameList.clear();
}
```